# How can test to ensure my iOS app retains its data when a user upgrade their phone?

Tags: ios, testing, upgrade

I have two phones. The first phone has a new version of my app that isn't released to the store yet.

- I backup phone #1 in iTunes.
- I connect phone #2 and restore from backup.

When I open phone #2, the iTunes version of the app was downloaded instead of having the new version transferred via the backup.

How do I test to make sure that my app will store will work when the user upgrades to a new phone?